# Accessing a private storage account from Azure Devops Hosted Agents

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-storage, azure-virtual-network

I'm trying to access an **azure blob storage** account to write some files from my pipeliens running with azure devops **hosted agent**.
We can't use yet the azure devops service tag with azure devops hosted agent

And I was wondering if there is a smart solution to access my blob storage from my hosted agents without opening it to all the internet.

Thank you in advance guys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you need to access Private Storage account with Microsoft-hosted agent.

As far as I know,  service tag is not currently supported by Azure Storage account when setting Firewall.

To meet your requirements, you can use script to get the current Microsoft-hosted agent IP and add it to Azure Storage account firewall whitelist with Azure CLI or Azure PowerShell.

For example:

```
steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: Set Rule'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: kevin0215
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: |
     $IP= Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | Select -exp ip
     
     $IP
     
     Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup" -AccountName "kevin0204" -IPAddressOrRange "$IP"
     
     
     
    preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: ' 3.1.0'

- task: AzureFileCopy@4
  displayName: 'AzureBlob File Copy'
  inputs:
    SourcePath: test
    azureSubscription: kevin0322
    Destination: AzureBlob
    storage: test
    ContainerName: 1


- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: Remove Rule'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: kevin0215
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: |
     $IP= Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | Select -exp ip
     
     $IP
     
     Remove-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup" -AccountName "kevin0204" -IPAddressOrRange "$IP"
     
     
    preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: ' 3.1.0'
```

**Explanation：**

You can add the IP to the firewall whitelist before uploading the file. After uploading, you can delete this IP.

**Note:**：The current azure storage account has a known limitation. Refer to this doc: [Limitations of Azure Storage Account IP network rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#grant-access-from-an-internet-ip-range).

When your Azure Devops Service organization and Azure Storage Account are in the same region, they will be accessed through private ip. This can cause intermittent access issues.